# Question regarding the LM7810 voltage regulator

Tags: lm78xx

Is there a simple way I can hook up this regulator to reduce the maximum output current from the 1A rating down to a 500mA maximum output without affecting the 10vdc output?

Comment: Use a load that only draws 500 mA at 10 V? The 7810 is a fixed voltage regulator. It will try to supply whatever current is needed to produce 10 V. If the load is a 10 ohm resistor, that will be 1 A, if it is a 100 kohm resistor that will be 0.1 mA.

Comment: Be sure to read [this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings) and  let us know if you still have questions.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by limiting the output current?

Comment: There are a few things you can do to the input side to limit the current, but I don't think it fits into the definition of simple.

Comment: So let's say that you have a 20 ohm load connected across the output of the LM7810 and that it's going merrily along, outputting 10 volts and pushing 500 milliamperes into the load. Now let's say that, all of a sudden, you connect another 20 ohm resistor across the load. What do you want to happen to the LM7810's output voltage and current?

Comment: Use a 500mA fuse?

Comment: Thanks for the reply's. I have a battery charger base that has a 10v/500mA wall transformer. The charger I.C. has no available app notes. Therefore, there must be a reason why it is supplied with a 500ma transformer and not something higher or lower. As I am trying to adapt it to 12vdc, I want to be careful. So my intent is to supply it with the same values as the transformer's.